# keyboard.send('enter') doesn't work on 'Save As' pop-up window

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-keyboard

I have a simple Python script that just clicks on already opened Browser window, preses 'Ctrl+s' and saves the page.

It works until 'Save As' pop-up window appears, so in below code ctrl+s works but the last doesn't

```
import keyboard, mouse

mouse.move(100,200)
mouse.click()
keyboard.send('ctrl+s')
keyboard.send('enter')
```

Any idea why?

Comment: What if you add a small delay? For example `time.sleep(5)` And as alternative, try using the Tab key and then enter